# make error cmath ‘::cos’ has not been declared

Tags: compiling, make, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv on Ubuntu. I have downloaded opencv 3.1 and done this:

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
```

but when I try to make it using `make` it shows these kind of errors:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
```

or

```
/usr/include/c++/5/cmath:199:11: error: ‘::cos’ has not been declared
```

and so on....

I think something is wrong with `math`, because the errors start from here:

```
>     In file included from /home/hadi/anaconda/include/math.h:71:0,
>                      from /usr/include/c++/5/cmath:44,
>                      from /home/hadi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:66,
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: First question I would try to answer is why it is searching include directory `/home/hadi/anaconda/include/` instead of the system's own `/usr/include/` for the `math.h` header file

Comment: I think it's because I defined python path to use anaconda. Can I change it so it would use `**/usr/include/**` instead?

Comment: Hmm... I wouldn't expect PYTHONPATH to affect compiler search paths - maybe I'm mistaken though

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with miniconda and OpenCV 3.3.1. It appears that cmake is finding these includes based on PATH, where miniconda was added. I temporarily removed it, deleted build directory, configured and build successfully. Moving the conda entry to the end of the PATH may be worth trying instead of removing it (but I've not tested that).